# Newton-Raphson Method for Non-linear System of 3 variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

I am trying to solve 3 non-linear system of 3 variables using the newton-raphson method in matlab. Here are the 3 non-linear equations:

\begin{equation} c[\alpha I+ k_f+k_d+k_ns+k_p(1-q)]-I \alpha =0 \end{equation}
\begin{equation} s[\lambda_b c P_C +\lambda_r (1-q)]- \lambda_b c P_C =0 \end{equation}
\begin{equation} q[\gamma +c k_p \frac{P_C}{P_Q}]- c k_p \frac{P_C}{P_Q}=0 \end{equation}

I need to find the values of c,s, and q  using the newton-raphson method.

=>
This is my matlab code :

```
    format long
clear;

%values of parameters
I=1200;
k_f= 6.7*10.^7;
k_d= 6.03*10.^8; 
k_n=2.92*10.^9; 
k_p=4.94*10.^9;
lambda_b= 0.0087;
lambda_r =835; 
gamma =2.74; 
alpha =1.14437*10.^-3;
P_C= 3 * 10.^(11);
P_Q= 2.87 * 10.^(10);

tol = 10.^-4;  %tol is a converge tolerance

%initial guess or values
c=1; 
s=0.015;
q=0.98;
x0= [c;s;q];

iter= 0; %iterations
xnew =[100;100;100];
while norm(xnew -x0) > tol
    iter= iter + 1;
%Defining the functions for c,s and q.
f = c * (alpha*I + k_f + k_d + k_n * s + k_p*(1-q))-I *alpha;
g = s * (lambda_b * c* P_C + lambda_r *(1-q))- lambda_b* c * P_C; 
h = q * ( gamma + c * k_p *(P_C / P_Q))- (c * k_p * (P_C / P_Q));

%Partial derivatives in terms of c,s and q.
dfdc = alpha*I + k_f + k_d + k_n * s + k_p*(1-q);
dfds = k_n *c ;
dfdq = - k_p *c;

dgdc = lambda_b * P_C *(s-1);
dgds = lambda_b * c* P_C + lambda_r *(1-q);
dgdq = - lambda_r * s;

dhdc = k_p *(P_C / P_Q)*(q-1);
dhds = 0;
dhdq = gamma + c * k_p *(P_C / P_Q);

%Jacobian matrix 
J = [dfdc dfds dfdq; dgdc dgds dgdq; dhdc dhds dhdq];

% Applying the Newton-Raphson method
xnew = x0 - J\[f;g;h];
disp(sprintf('iter=%6.15f,  c=%6.15f,  s=%6.15f, q=%6.15f', iter,xnew)); 
end
```

can someone please check my code, there are some errors so, its not working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I run your code without error. Maybe expand on the errors you're getting?

Comment: what values did you get for c,s,q?

Comment: In my matlab code:

In the line: while abs(xnew -x0) > tol. I comparing a vector to a scalar. so, can i define tol as a vector like this: tol= [10.^4;10.^4:10.^4];

Comment: In Newton-Rhapson, you compare the *norm* of a vector. That might be your error. You want to terminate when $$||x_{n}-x_{n-1}|| < \textrm{tol}.$$

Comment: yes. that's my problem. but So far, I manage to get only 1 iterations but the values of c,s and q are incorrects. And I want to get at least more than 2 or 3 iterations automatically after I ran the program. So that, tolerance will stop it when it converges and it can give the accurate values of c,s and q.

Comment: So, start by using the norm of the vector and see what you get. You're trying to find a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that solves your equation. It doesn't make sense to stop if only one of your coordinates is near that point.

Comment: you mean use norm instead of abs? here tol is scalar, do I need to change into vector? norm is vector?I comparing a vector to a scalar. is that right?

Comment: Tolerance is a scalar. You must compute when the difference of the previous solution and the current solution is very small. Smallness is measured as a scalar. `abs` when applied to a vector gives the element-wise absolute value. You need to use `norm` instead. `norm` will return a scalar. You compare a scalar to a scalar. Perhaps revisit the basics of the Newton-Rhapson method before writing more code.

Comment: Also, your partial derivatives are wrong. Check those. $\partial f/\partial s = ck_n$, not $sk_n$.

Comment: ok. I got that Tolerance is a scalar and I will use norm  instead. but here $\left\|(x_{n} -x_{n+1})\right\|$ contains 3 variables c,s and q. so comparing vector with scalar, does tolerance going to work? so it can stop and converge it.

Comment: The norm of a vector is a scalar. You must understand this before attempting to write code.

Comment: thank you for your help. Just change abs into norm. now, where should I need to focus on to get the correct values of c, s and q because I want to get atleast more than 2 iterations and tolerance to stop and converge it.

Comment: My code using the standard newton method algorithm requires 12 steps to converge from the initial value of $c=1, s=1, q=1$. If you fix your math errors, you should find the same result.

Comment: I don't have matlab at home. I like to run my code now. As I remember when I run the code at uni, I was getting not good values of c,s,q.  I will get back tomorrow, how it goes? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I am concern about this line:                               disp(sprintf('iter=%6.15f,  c=%6.15f,  s=%6.15f, q=%6.15f', iter,xnew));    I want to display xnew as new and accurate values of c,s,q. did I write the code correctly. is this code giving the update values of c,s,q as xnew?

Comment: Yes, it should. I never use `sprintf`, but the documentation for it is widely available online. If you're curious, just type `xnew` without any semicolon and it will output the value.

Comment: If you are still having trouble, I will post my code for you tomorrow evening. Simply ask.

Comment: That would be great sir.  Thank you very much

Comment: @Arkamis Could please send me your code. I have got 12 iterations with initial guess of $c=1,q=1,s=1$ but in my 1st iteration: $iter=1.000000000000000,c=1.000000000000000, s=1.000000000000000, q=1.000000000000000$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Newton's method in general in MATLAB code. Define a function `J` that takes a vector `x` as its argument and returns the Jacobian; likewise, define a function `f` that takes a vector `x` as its argument and represents the vector-valued function. For instance, if $$\mathbf{f}(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} x^2 + y^2  \\ 2x-y \end{pmatrix}$$ then we would write:

```
f = @(x)[ x(1)^2+x(2)^2;...
          2*x(1)-x(2)];
J = @(x)[ 2*x(1), 2*x(2);...
          2, -1];
```

Next, use this code to solve the system. I wrote this blindly; there might be a trivial error in there somewhere, as I am not near a MATLAB machine at the moment.

```
tol = 1e-4; % Or some other tolerance
err = 1000; % Any value larger than tol
x = x_initial; % However this is defined.
iter = 1; max_iter = 30; % Or whatever.
while (err > tol)
    delta_x = J(x)\(-f(x)); % Compute x_{n+1}-x_n
    err = norm(delta_x);
    x = x + delta_x;
    iter = iter + 1;
    [iter x'] % This line simply outputs the current iteration and the solution. You can dress this up by using sprintf if you like.
    if (iter > max_iter)
        disp 'Failed to converge';
        break;
    end
end
```